# Get calories from nutritional information

Tags: diet, calories, nutrition-information

I'm eating a pack of biscuits and on the label the following information is given:

> Nutritional information per 100g of product
>
> Carbohydrates  -     75g
>   Proteins            -      6g
>   Fat -  15g
>   Cholesterol  -   0mg
>   Energy  -     468kcal
>   Calcium             -     60mg
>   Iron                -      8mg

I would like to know more about this information. What does the information in grams mean? Should I be only concerned about the calories? How can I get the calorie information?

Comment: Per the FAQ, nutrition questions are expected to pertain directly to a stated fitness goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to keep in mind the following:

- 1 gram of fat yields 9 calories
- 1 gram of carbohydrate yields 4 calories
- 1 gram of protein yields 4 calories

so for the food you are eating:

```
Carbohydrates - 75g  ==>75*4 = 300 cal
Proteins - 6g ==>6*4 = 24 cal
Fat - 15g ==>15*9 = 135 cal

==>Carb+protein+fat gives total calories = 300+24+135 = 459 cal
```

as for the vitamin/minerals:

```
Cholesterol - 0mg
Calcium - 60mg
Iron - 8mg
```

Those are not related to calories. 
In general, nutrition labels should have a **percentage daily value** on the right side, which for these vitamins tells you how much percent of the **required** daily value that you need, does your food contain.

The vitamin/mineral daily requirements depend on  your **age and gender** and is about how much (**grams,mg,mcg.etc..**) of each is required per day. You can check [Health CANADA's](http://www.hc-sc.gc.ca/index-eng.php) website, they have a lot of info.